# React Native navigation ref always null

Tags: react-native

I have the following:

```
import {navigationRef} from "./wherever"

<NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
```

In the navigation file I import, I have this

```
import React from 'react';

const navigationRef = React.createRef();

const navigate = (name, params) => {
    console.log(navigationRef)
    navigationRef.current?.navigate(name, params);
}

export default {
    navigate
}
```

But when in my code I try to call the following:

```
import navigation from './wherever';

navigation.navigate('wherever')
```

the console log always shows

```
{"current": null}
```

and so the navigation never kicks in. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

the rubber duck technique in action, I answered my own question in the act of describing it to you all!

I was simply missing an export.

```
export default {
    navigate,
    navigationRef
}
```

And so I changed my import like so:

```
import navigation from "./wherever"

<NavigationContainer ref={navigation.navigationRef}>
```